# How to configure Select2 via data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

According to the documentation, I should be able to set some configuration via data-attributes on the select tag.

https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes

In my code, I tried this:

```
<select id="customer_select_form_customer" name="customer_select_form[customer]" class="select2-ajax-enabled form-control" style="width: 500px" data-theme="bootstrap4" data-ajax--url="/customer/ajaxList" data-ajax--cache="true" data-select2-id="customer_select_form_customer" ></select>
```

I tried to initialize this with the following, but it does nothing:

```
// enable the customer ajax list
$('.select2-ajax-enabled').select2({});
```

I also tried to set the parameters, and have them override, but that didn’t work either:

```
// enable the customer ajax list
$('.select2-ajax-enabled').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: 'true'
    }
});
```

Is there a configuration/setting that I’m missing to get the data attributes to work?
If I specify the whole config and pass it to select2, it works as expected.

I’m using jQuery v3.3.1 and Select2 4.0.6-rc.1

Answer (score 1):

Following up on this because I found an answer:
This is not working due to a bug on v4.0.6.  I reverted to v4.0.5 and it's working using the code that I included in the initial post.

For reference:
https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/5169